# Text recognition with Unity without using Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, text-recognition

I have checked many posts about text recognition with Unity. But every post is suggesting Vuforia.

Also, Vuforia text recognition is [deprecated](https://forum.unity.com/threads/why-is-text-recognition-deprecated.502216/).

According to Vuforia it only detects serif and sans-serif fonts.

I want my application to detect even handwritten text up to some extent.

So my question is 'is there any SDK or anything else which will help to detect handwritten text too?'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do so with OpenCV and the tesseract-ocr API. It requires you know C++ and make a plug-in with it.

Comment: Thank you, @PassetCronUs for the suggestion. Right now I am not aware of C++.

Comment: No problem. And I think that's probably the only free way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're allowed to use network in your Unity application, you can integrate Google Cloud Vision which will do it all for you.

There's a project on GitHub called UnityCloudVision which should do the dirty work for you.

https://github.com/comoc/UnityCloudVision

Comment: @zyonneo sure, you'd have to upload a screenshot or just the texture on the object to GCV, but yes

Comment: but  I want to use it using device camera.Please have a look at this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57181517/how-to-use-google-cloud-vision-along-with-unity-for-recognising-text-using-mobil

Comment: OK, then simply upload the captured texture to google cloud vision. There are plenty of samples around on how to capture texture from an input device

Comment: Any examples? If I am using camera means it will be giving a video feed.So how does it help capturing the text .